# WCF service not able to get the CPU utilization when CPU is 100 percent

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF . I have an application with following components: monitoring service, worker service and a UI.

Monitoring service monitors the machine in which the worker runs.
Monitor sends the cpu utilization to the UI.
Worker service is  hosted by the monitor service.
Monitor service is hosted on console.

Issue:

When the worker service occupies 100% of the CPU, the monitor does not send data to the UI and the UI is not able to draw the graph.
Any console.writeline in the worker service comes to the console of the monitoring service.
When process started by the worker service crashes, the monitor also crashes.

Pls help me how to deal with it .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the situation by putting your monitoring UI on another machine.

You can also give your monitoring process higher CPU priority than your worker service.

But your real problem is: why is the worker process using 100% of CPU?